# Getting closest angle from array of angles clockwise and anticlockwise

Tags: javascript

I have four angles of div corners from origin, I have one more new angle suppose θ to compare to these angles, now I need the closest angle anticlockwise and clockwise to θ.

```
θ = -26 // new angle
a = [-15, 15, -165, -195]; // array of angles

anticlockangle = ? // closest angle anticlockwise to θ from array
clockangle = ? // closest angle clockwise to θ from array
```

Comment: In your example, which angles are the correct answer here? How do you find these angles by hand from the list?

Comment: I am rotating the div clockwise and anticlockwise, array contains initial angles of div corners and θ is the angle where the div would touch its parent in anticlockwise direction, my question is to get the closest corner from θ in anticlockwise direction.

Comment: I have a circle around div with radius and circle origin =  origin of the div.

Comment: "my question is to get the closest corner from θ in anticlockwise direction." So which one in the list `a` in your example is the correct answer? How do you calculate that answer by hand? Describe **in words** the steps you take to solve this. (I don't know how to do it. These are the steps I would take to solve the problem.)

Comment: sorry, correct answer is -15  for anticlockwise and for clockwise is -165 , the minimum distance from the point at θ to the corners in clockwise and anticlockwise direction, hope you understand

Comment: A circle has 360 degrees, so I would first align all angles to +/-180 degrees or 0...360 degrees with adding 360 and modulo etc.. because -195 is out of these 2 default ranges. Then get the absolute differences in ascending order. Check starting from the smallest whether the direction is ok or not - wrapping from 360 to 0/ 180 to +180 has to be thought of too. Does this help?

Comment: Now how do you calculate "the minimum distance from the point at θ to the corners in clockwise direction"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion this is the most optimal solution. We sort the array by order then we look for the next value of the array thanks to find and our condition.

```js
const θ = 90 // new angle
let a = [-15, 15, -165, -195]; // array of angle
a.sort((a, b) => a-b);

let anticlockangle;
for (i = θ; i > -360; i -= 1) {
  if (a.find(element => element === i)) {
    anticlockangle = i;
    break;
  }
}
if (anticlockangle === undefined) {
 anticlockangle = a[a.length - 1]; 
}

let clockangle;
for (i = θ; i < 360; i += 1) {
  if (a.find(element => element === i)) {
    clockangle = i;
    break;
  }
}
if (clockangle === undefined) {
  clockangle = a[0];
}

console.log(anticlockangle);
console.log(clockangle);
```

Comment: This won't work as expected. It finds the first angle less than theta, which won't necessarily be the closest. Also, it doesn't handle edge cases where all angles are less than theta or all are greater. (My original solution won't handle that either.)

Comment: @BrandonGano "It finds the first angle less than theta" It won't even do that because theta isn't used in the solution.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh This answer is incorrect. It only works for the example you gave, but will give incorrect answers for almost all other examples you can think of.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, It is. θ === theta

Comment: @BrandonGano Oh...I was seeing that as a zero in the comparisons...smh

Comment: Just add an exception if no number is found. I take care of editing my code to make it work.

Comment: @ag-dev Will your code give the correct answer if `const θ = 0` and `let a = [185, -185]`? What about `const θ = 0` and `let a = [-175, 175]`?

Comment: Or `const θ = 10` and `let a = [20, 30]`?

Comment: See my anser below - not Javascript perfect, but taking wraparounds in account.

Comment: Code updated and run correctly, Sorry for my first fast answer.

Comment: @ag-dev: Sorry, your code works for this specific question and not for any general approach with float values and neither with values of angles wrapping 1... several times, what about a = [-178.83, +355.73, -450, +720.5, -283.42, +63.5, -59.34] and θ from ...-360 ... + 360 ... degrees.

Comment: He never spoke about float values. 
This request is not detailed enough to know the use cases. If he wishes to work on an angle of more than 360, it suffices to adapt the code accordingly ...

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most optimal solution, but something like this should get you close:

```
const theta = -26
const angles = [-15, 15, -165, -195]
let lowestAngle = null
let highestAngle = null
let previousAngle = null
let nextAngle = null
for (let index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
  const angle = angles[index]
  if (lowestAngle === null || angle < lowestAngle) {
    lowestAngle = angle
  }
  if (highestAngle === null || angle > highestAngle) {
    highestAngle = angle
  }
  if (angle < theta) {
    // If this is the first angle less than theta or if this angle is closer to theta than the current previous, save it
    if (previousAngle === null || angle > previousAngle) {
      previousAngle = angle
    }
  }
  else if (angle > theta) {
    // If this is the first angle greater than theta or if this angle is closer to theta than the current next, save it
    if (nextAngle === null || angle < nextAngle) {
      nextAngle = angle
    }
  }
  else {
    // angle matches theta...what do you want to do here?
  }
}
// No previous angle found; loop around to the highest angle
if (previousAngle === null) {
  previousAngle = highestAngle
}
// No next angle found; loop around to the lowest angle
if (nextAngle === null) {
  nextAngle = lowestAngle
}
```

Comment: This should handle all edge cases now. I'm assuming you want to consider the angles as "wrapping" around the circle and you always want to get results for previous and next.

Answer (score 0):

My solution takes in account wraparounds and works for any angles. Even if input range exceeds the standard ranges 0°...360° and -180° ... +180° (as it does with the -195 value in example) or if the values are float and not int.
I now fixed the program and wrote it in proper javascript - and tested it on https://playcode.io/

```
θi = -26;
ai = [-15, 15, -165, -195];
// loop test: ai = [-161.5, -82.6, +53.7, +174.8]; // array of angles

a = [0, 0, 0, 0]
for (i = 0; i < ai.length; i++)
{
    a[i] = getValueBetween0And360(ai[i]);
}
console.log(`a = ${ai} (${a})`);

// loop test: for(θi = -400; θi <= +400; θi += 33.3) // new angle
{
    θ = getValueBetween0And360(θi);
    //console.log(`θi = ${θi}, θ = ${θ}`);
    
    
    ccw = ai[getIndexOfNearestAngle(a, θ, -1)]; // closest angle anticlockwise to θ from array
    cw = ai[getIndexOfNearestAngle(a, θ, +1)]; // closest angle clockwise to θ from array
    console.log(`θ = ${θi.toFixed(1)} (${θ.toFixed(1)}),\tccw = ${ccw.toFixed(1)} (${getValueBetween0And360(ccw).toFixed(1)}),\tcw = ${cw.toFixed(1)} (${getValueBetween0And360(cw).toFixed(1)})`);

}

function getValueBetween0And360(input)
{
    if (input < 0)
    {
        return (input + (Math.trunc(-input / 360) + 1.0) * 360.0) % 360.0;
    }
    return input % 360.0;
}

function getValueBetweenPlusMinus180(input)
{
    in360 = getValueBetween0And360(input);
    return 180 < in360
             ? in360 - 360
             : in360;
}

// sign = +1 for clock wise (cw), -1 for counter clock wise (ccw)
// starting from angle θ towards found angle in array a
function getIndexOfNearestAngle(a, θ, sign)
{
    var iF = -1;
    var diffF = 1000;

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        var diff = sign * getDiffClockWise(a[i], θ);
        var diffPos = getValueBetween0And360(diff);
        //console.log(`start a[${i}] = ${a[i]}, diffPos = ${diffPos}, iF = ${iF}, diffF = ${diffF}, sign = ${sign}`);
        
        if (diffPos < diffF)
        {
            diffF = diffPos;
            iF = i;
        }
        //console.log(`end   a[${i}] = ${a[i]}, diffPos = ${diffPos}, iF = ${iF}, diffF = ${diffF}`);
    }
    
    return iF;
}
 
function getDiffClockWise(a, θ)
{
    //console.log(`diff = ${a - θ}, a = ${a}, θ = ${θ}`)
    return a - θ;
}
```

The result is:

```
a = -15,15,-165,-195 (345,15,195,165)
θ = -26.0 (334.0),  ccw = -165.0 (195.0),   cw = -15.0 (345.0)
```

If the `// loop test:` is replaced in the code with nothing, it reports these examples showing wrap arounds and float work too:

```
a = -161.5,-82.6,53.7,174.8 (198.5,277.4,53.7,174.8)
θ = -400.0 (320.0), ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
θ = -366.7 (353.3), ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
θ = -333.4 (26.6),  ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
θ = -300.1 (59.9),  ccw = 53.7 (53.7),  cw = 174.8 (174.8)
θ = -266.8 (93.2),  ccw = 53.7 (53.7),  cw = 174.8 (174.8)
θ = -233.5 (126.5), ccw = 53.7 (53.7),  cw = 174.8 (174.8)
θ = -200.2 (159.8), ccw = 53.7 (53.7),  cw = 174.8 (174.8)
θ = -166.9 (193.1), ccw = 174.8 (174.8),    cw = -161.5 (198.5)
θ = -133.6 (226.4), ccw = -161.5 (198.5),   cw = -82.6 (277.4)
θ = -100.3 (259.7), ccw = -161.5 (198.5),   cw = -82.6 (277.4)
θ = -67.0 (293.0),  ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
θ = -33.7 (326.3),  ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
θ = -0.4 (359.6),   ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
θ = 32.9 (32.9),    ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
θ = 66.2 (66.2),    ccw = 53.7 (53.7),  cw = 174.8 (174.8)
θ = 99.5 (99.5),    ccw = 53.7 (53.7),  cw = 174.8 (174.8)
θ = 132.8 (132.8),  ccw = 53.7 (53.7),  cw = 174.8 (174.8)
θ = 166.1 (166.1),  ccw = 53.7 (53.7),  cw = 174.8 (174.8)
θ = 199.4 (199.4),  ccw = -161.5 (198.5),   cw = -82.6 (277.4)
θ = 232.7 (232.7),  ccw = -161.5 (198.5),   cw = -82.6 (277.4)
θ = 266.0 (266.0),  ccw = -161.5 (198.5),   cw = -82.6 (277.4)
θ = 299.3 (299.3),  ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
θ = 332.6 (332.6),  ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
θ = 365.9 (5.9),    ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
θ = 399.2 (39.2),   ccw = -82.6 (277.4),    cw = 53.7 (53.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay depending on ag-dev's first answer in revision history, I came up with following,

```js
θ = -26 // new angle
a = [-15, 15, -165, -195]; // array of angles

anticlockangle = getClosestAngle(θ,a,false);
clockangle = getClosestAngle(θ,a,true);

console.log(anticlockangle);
console.log(clockangle);

 function getClosestAngle(θ, arr, is_clock) {
    arr.sort();
    return is_clock ? arr.find(element => element < θ) : arr.find(element => element > θ);
  }
```